# Scrapy: Default values for items & fields. What is the best implementation?

Tags: scrapy

As far as I could find out from the documentation and various discussions on the net, the ability to add default values to fields in a scrapy item has been removed.

**This doesn't work**

```
category = Field(default='null')
```

So my question is: what is a good way to initialize fields with a default value?

I already tried to implement it as a item pipeline as suggested here, without any success.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scrapy-users/-v1p5W41VDQ

Comment: Why no luck?  what happened?

Comment: it just doesn't work. I implemented an item pipeline and added it to the ITEM_PIPELINES in my setting.py.  After that I expected to get certain fields populated with default data in case they could not be filled by scrapy... unfortunately the fields remain empty

Comment: Are you sure your pipeline's `process_item` is running? Paste in your pipeline code here so we can see it.

Answer (score 3):

figured out what the problem was. the pipeline is working (code follows for other people's reference). my problem was, that I am appending values to a field. and I wanted the default method work on one of these listvalues... chose a different way and it works. I am now implementing it with a custom setDefault processor method.

```
class DefaultItemPipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    item.setdefault('amz_VendorsShippingDurationFrom', 'default')
    item.setdefault('amz_VendorsShippingDurationTo', 'default')
    # ...
    return item
```

Comment: hey, if default values aren't set and a `Field` isn't filled in for a given item, is it just considered empty or does it return `None` or something?!

Answer (score -1):

Typically, a constructor is used to initialize fields.

```
class SomeItem(scrapy.Item):

    id = scrapy.Field()
    category = scrapy.Field()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self['category'] = 'null'  # set default value
```

This may not be a clean solution, but it avoids unnecessary pipelines.